# Is Haar cascade classifier suitable for bottle label detection?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

Can OpenCV's Haar feature-based cascade classifiers be trained to **detect** labels in the bottle's body?

I've been struggling to create my own detector heuristically by using edge detectors such as Canny, Sobel, Laplacian and HED.

But I've found that a bottle's labels isn't so trivial to describe by its edges as I have imagined, neither I can trust edge detectors since most of them is dependent upon hysteresis thresholding values.

[image: success]
[image: fail]

So I was wondering whether I should try another approach using Haar cascade.

I have never trained a Haar classifier by myself. I've been told that it might work well for blocky objects.

How many positives and negatives samples do I need?

Comment: This might work too: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html

Comment: I'm not looking for feature matching or ways of recognize a certain label. My intent is just detection: whether or not there is a label on an image and where it is (its rect).

Comment: might be possible, but I wouldnt bet on it.

Comment: what would you bet on instead?